# Take the average and go through the list again. Count the amount of numbers greater than the average and the amount of numbers less than the average

Tags: python

I'm trying to figure out the 2nd half of this question using python 3 but can't seem to figure it out. The first half of the code that I have is the following below...

> > > A = [1,2,3,4]
> > >       print(average(A))
> > >       2.5

```
num = int(input('How many numbers: '))
total_sum = 0
for n in range(num):
    numbers = float(input('Enter number : '))
    total_sum += numbers
avg = total_sum/num
print('Average of ', num, ' numbers is :', avg)

number = int(input("Enter number: "))
if number < 2.5:
    print("Your number is smaller than 2.5")
else:
    print("Your number is greater than 2.5")
```

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: num = int(input('How many numbers: '))
total_sum = 0
for n in range(num):
    numbers = float(input('Enter number : '))
    total_sum += numbers
avg = total_sum/num
print('Average of ', num, ' numbers is :', avg)

number = int(input("Enter number: "))
if number < 2.5:
    print("Your number is smaller than 2.5)
else:
    print("Your number is greater than 2.5")

Comment: In order to "go through the list again", you have to have a list. For example, you can start off with an empty list (`numbers = []`), and then `append` each number to that list. Meanwhile, to compare with the average, you have to compare with `avg`, not `2.5`. Hopefully, that's enough to get you unstuck.

Answer (score 0):

Save the numbers in list. Sort the list and check the number which is equivalent to or greater than an average number. U can then easily find the count of numbers less than and greater than avarage number.